# Data binding from radio buttons angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I tried to make a form with radio buttons. I use angular and I want to get the value of the checked radio button. I tried with ng-model but this didn't work.

Code:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-default active" style="width: 100%">
    <input ng-model="typeOfFood" type="radio" checked="checked" ng-value="'recomandation'" /> Recomandations
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default" style="width: 100%">
    <input ng-model="typeOfFood" type="radio" ng-value="'apperitive'"/> Apperitives
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default" style="width: 100%">
    <input ng-model="typeOfFood" type="radio" ng-value="'main'"/> Mains
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default" style="width: 100%">
    <input ng-model="typeOfFood" type="radio" id="desserts" ng-value="'dessert'"/> Desserts
  </label>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('demoApp')
  .controller('MenuCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.typeOfFood;

    $scope.option = function() {
      console.log($scope.typeOfFood);
    }
  });
```

I received the variable "typeOfFood" undefined in controller. How can I fix this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Soooo.... is `typeOfFood` definitely defined in your controller? Def the same case etc?!

Comment: yes, it has the same case

Comment: show your controller

Comment: I have just added the controller.

Comment: when are you calling `$scope.option`?  you aren't setting `$scope.typeOfFood` to any value when the controller is first initialized...

Comment: replace ng-value="'something'" with value="something". intialize $scope.typeOfFood with "main" for example;

Comment: I tried with value and to initialize the $scope.typeOfFood with "main", but I received everytime "main". I call the option on a button after I choose an item.

Comment: Why is your into inside your label?

Comment: I meant input. Why is your I out inside your label

Comment: Also in your current setup there is no benefit to using ng-value rather then the normal value

Comment: I think your problem is that you don't have anything that groups your radio buttons try putting them in a form element

Comment: And look at this example here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors:

You are initializing angular main module in a bad way, use this:

```
angular.module('demoApp',[])
```

Without the array you are trying to find demoApp instead of creating a new instance.

Also you din't use **ng-controller** and **ng-app** directives.

If you want to use the options function call it with **ng-click** directive:

```
 <label class="btn btn-default" style="width: 100%">
      <input ng-click="option()" ng-model="typeOfFood" type="radio" id="desserts" ng-value="'dessert'" /> Desserts
    </label>
```

**Codepen:** 
http://codepen.io/armellajuan/pen/QyKPpO

Maybe this book will help you in this details:
http://www.angularjsbook.com/angular-basics/chapters/introduction/

Comment: I don't want to create the controller, I want to find "demoApp" that is created early. ng-controller and ng-app are initialize in the "index". The definition of the controller is ok. Thanks for help.

Comment: I updated the code with the button to see the value of typeOfFood. It's working, so maybe you have another error in other place. Did you checked the console?

Comment: I didn't have any errors, but I found the problem. It's from the "data-toggle='buttons'".